# is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity.Listview1Adapter, String)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have class QuranArabUtils

```
public class QuranArabicUtils {
public static Spannable getTajweed(Context context, String s) {
}

}
```

And this is my adapter listview

```
    @Override
        public View getView(final int _position, View _v, ViewGroup _container) {
            LayoutInflater _inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View _view = _v;
            if (_view == null) {
                _view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.tet, null);
            }
            
            final LinearLayout linear1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
            final TextView textview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            
            
                textview1.setText(QuranArabicUtils.getTajweed(this, aYat.get((int)_position).get("a").toString()));

        
            
            return _view;
        }
```

I call argumet to

```
textview1.setText(QuranArabicUtils.getTajweed(this, aYat.get((int)_position).get("a").toString()));
```

How to conect argument getTajweed() in class QuranArabUtils to listview adapter? I got error " The  method getTajweed(Context, String) in the type QuranArabicUtils is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity.Listview1Adapter, String)"

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

you have to replace

```
textview1.setText(QuranArabicUtils.getTajweed(this, aYat.get((int)_position).get("a").toString()));
```

To

```
textview1.setText(QuranArabicUtils.getTajweed(getApplicationContext(), aYat.get((int)_position).get("a").toString()));
```